# Cypress: How to convert list of text into arrrays?

Tags: arrays, cypress

I have a HTML code like this

```
<ul class="menu-main-nav-container">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
        <ul>
            <li>About1</li>
            <li>About2</li>
            <li>About3</li>
        </ul>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Links</li>
</ul>
```

What i want to achieve is to get all the text of **li's** and convert it to array so that i can use each array for comparison to other values. but the twist is the **li's** are constantly changing

So far i have this code on cypress

```
it('List to array', () => {
        cy.get('*[class^="menu-main-nav-container"]').eq(0).then($text => {
            const text = $text.text().toString().slice('')
            cy.log(text[0])
})
})
```

It just log the text 'H' for now but i want to achieve is **text = ["Home", "About", "Contact", Links" ]** so that i can compose **text[0]** that i can use

I'm so stuck right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
it('List to array', () => {
  var list = []

  cy.get('ul[class="menu-main-nav-container"] > li')
    .each(($ele) => {
      list.push($ele.text().trim())
    })
    .then(() => {
      cy.log(list[0]) //prints Home
    })
})
```

Or, you can do also something like this:

```js
var list = []
cy.get('ul[class="menu-main-nav-container"] > li')
  .then(($ele) => {
    const list = Array.from($ele, (el) => el.innerText)
  })
  .then(() => {
    cy.log(list[0]) //prints Home
  })
```

Comment: Wooah! thanks is perfectly working fine! But can i use the list[0] globally?

Comment: Yes you can as you have declared the list variable globally.

Answer (score 3):

One way, you can take advantage of Cypress selecting multiple elements, then convert elements to texts

```js
cy.get('.menu-main-nav-container')
  .find('li')   // gets all li including sub-menu ones!
  .then($els => {
    return Array.from($els).map(el => el.innerText)
  })
  .should('deep.eq', ['Home', 'About', 'About1', 'About2', 'About3', 'Contact', 'Links'])
```

or top-level only

```js
cy.get('.menu-main-nav-container')
  .children('li')   // gets main menu options
  .then($els => {
    return Array.from($els).map(el => el.innerText)
  })
  .should('deep.eq', ['Home', 'About', 'Contact', 'Links'])
```

[Docs reference](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/children#Examples)

Comment: This is also working fine. Thank you for the .children() tips it's really helpful

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, `.children()` should have `li` selector, that is should be `.children('li')`.

Comment: Even without 'li' in the .children() it's working perfectly